# Regarding the passing away of Bruce E. Trumbo

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Today, it has been noted (by [Nick Cox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62129623#62129623) in [Ten Fold](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold)) that recently Dr. Bruce E. Trumbo, professor emeritus of statistics, biostatistics, and mathematics, author of two books, and most prominently [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/85665/bruceet) of the top users in our community, [passed away](https://www.dignitymemorial.com/obituaries/springfield-il/bruce-trumbo-10852976) at his home on July $8, 2022.$

He was a prolific teacher and a magnificent explainer that was reflected in his numerous posts here. As summed [here](https://magazine.amstat.org/blog/2022/10/01/obituaries-for-october-2022/):

> Bruce loved to teach and devoted his life to teaching and learning. His teaching spanned seven decades. He taught his last class at CSU East Bay the week before the first Bay Area COVID-19 lockdown. After leaving the university, he continued to teach on the Stack Exchange website as BruceET, answering more than 3,000 probability and statistics questions; he often included R code for demonstration purposes. Through these efforts, Bruce earned 49,382 reputation points, placing him in the top 0.48 percent overall. His impact was impressive; he reached ~2.6 million people.

For the sake of cognizance of the entire community, this has been reported here. His absence will be felt here and he will be missed greatly. For the years to come, his posts would inevitably help many.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated his profile with links to both obituaries.

Comment: Thanks @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica. I knew mods would work promptly. Thanks to Nick Cox, we have been able to inform about his sad demise to the community.

Comment: Oh no, what a great loss. My condolences to the family.

Comment: Note the *AmStat News* obituary references the Bruce E. Trumbo Scholarship Endowment Fund at California State University, East Bay.

Comment: This post has resulting in me wanting to go back and read more of Bruce's posts to learn from him.  People who knew him, I'm sure, have fond personal memories of him.  For those of use who didn't know him, we will eternally have his knowledge which he so generously shared.  Thank you Bruce.

Comment: In reading a few of his posts, I came across this kind and encouraging comment Bruce left for another community member who was a bit discouraged.  I think it speaks volumes about Bruce's wonderful kindness and his enthusiasm to share his expertise: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476795/understanding-medical-testing/476875#comment880718_476875

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket that's a trait of a visionary teacher.